# Откуда взялось местоимение «её» и куда пропало «ея»?

Tags: этимология, история-языка, местоимения

Интересно было бы узнать больше об истории и этимологии  личных местоимений третьего лица.

Помнится, я где-то читал, что они якобы происходят от слова «оный». Как вы считаете?  Может быть, все как раз наоборот, я не знаю.

Но как бы то ни было, можно заметить определенное сходство косвенных падежных форм местоимений с соответствующими окончаниями прилагательных. То есть,  всех форм кроме род-вин. женского рода «её», которая на первый взгляд ничего общего  с современным парадигом прил. окончаний не имеет, разве что она происходит от окончания им. падежа среднего рода. Но неужели такое возможно?

В русской литературе XIX века нередко встречается слово «ея»,  соответствующее тогдашнему написанию окончания род. жен. «ыя». Правда, насколько я знаю, в то время оно употреблялось в основном только в письменной речи  и притом исключительно  как форма второго падежа, а, возможно, было время, когда все было по-другому.

Итак,  хотелось бы узнать откуда взялось «её» (и, если релевантно, как оно оттеснило «ея») . Слово «самоё» (т.е. вин. жен. слова «сам») тут при чем?

Comment: Вопрос скорее для rus.stackexchange.com

Comment: но неужели такое возможно? Да, такое возможно и называется супплетивизм - формы косвенных падежей и именительного могут образовываться о разных основ. Такое бывает сплошь и рядом.

Comment: Формальный ответ - ея превратилось в её согласно орфографической реформе 1918 года.  Но как возникло это "ея", и как получилось, что стали произносить "её" вместо "ея" - это более сложный вопрос.

Comment: @shabunc А почему окончание средного рода стало местоимением женского рода?

Comment: какое окончание?

Comment: @user31264 Так когда-то «ея» было местоимение как род. рода, так и вин. рода?

Comment: @shabunc окончание типа «ое»  в «белое платье».Другие окончания не похожи на «ее».

Comment: в каком именно слове "ое" - какое местоимение вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: речь идет о окончаниях прилагательных, и как они стали местоимениями.Так что разве это возможно,что окончание «ое,ее» в «белое» превратилось в местоимение «ее».

Comment: Почему вы решили, что прилагательные стали местоимениями? Какие именно прилагательные?

Comment: В старославянском личное местоимение ж. р. в им. п. было [*ja], вин. п. - [jǫ], что должно было бы дать совр. *ю (что в точности соответствовало бы совр. окончаниям прилагательных), но оно не сохранилось, вместо него с развитием категории одушевленность-неодушевленность стал использовался род. п. этого же местоимения, [jeję], который и дал **ея**, так что средний род тут совершенно ни при чём.

Comment: Это местоимения стали окончаниями прилагательных, а не наоборот.

Comment: @shabunc я где-то читал, что местоимения происходят oт слова «оный». «бел-ого» похоже на «его». «бел-ых» похоже на «их» и т.д.

Comment: Смотрите, вы спрашиваете - есть гипотеза А, но почему она верна? А надо бы спрашивать - есть гипотеза А - верна ли она? Но если она верна - тогда почему? А если неверна - тогда почему вон то-то?

Но  YellowSky уже правильно раъяснил

Comment: @shabunc А я спросил  «но неужели такое возможно?» а вы ответил «возможно». Извините, если я не так понял ваш коммент.

Comment: но меня-то вы спросили - но как прилагательное среднего рода стало местоимением женского рода - а ответ таков, что вопрос некорректен.

Comment: К прилагательным добавлялись личные местоимения, образовывая определённую форму прилагательных, типа с определённым артиклем, это называется [местоименные прилагательные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Артикль#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B3.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5), другое название  – членные прилагательные, от них и происходят современные русские полные прилагательные.

Comment: @shabunc А я спросил  «но неужели такое возможно?» а вы ответил «возможно». Извините, если я не так понял ваш коммент.

Comment: Нет, тогда мне стоило изъясняться яснее - я имел ввиду, что возможно чтобы в разных падежах местоимение образовывалось от разных основ - это бывает часто. Но прилагательные тут ни при чём.

Comment: @shabunc Да, все верно. Скорее всего, я не так написал вопрос. Нужно признаться, мой русский не ахти. Понимать я типо понимаю, а писать...@yellowsky Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: у вас замечательный русский, просто отличный, так что просто друг друга не поняли )

Comment: @V.V. - А это вы о каком издании? Во 2-м издании 1983 года это §197, «История личного местоимения 3-го лица», там есть и о возникновении формы **её**.

Comment: §199.3 изд, 1990 год,да,там все есть.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сведу всю вышеупомянутую информацию в один ответ.

В праславянском языке не было личных местоимений 3-го лица, их роль выполняли различные указательные местоимения, самыми распространёнными из которых были

> **тъ** (**то**, **та**), склонявшиеся как **того**, **тому**, и т. д.;
>
> **онъ** (**оно**, **она**), склонявшиеся как **оного**, **оному**, и т. д.;
>
> ***и** (***ѥ** [*je], ***ꙗ** [*ja]), склонявшиеся как **ѥго**, **ѥму**, и т. д.;

Очень рано, похоже, что ещё в позднепраславянскую эпоху, местоимения **онъ** и ***и**, употреблявшиеся в одном значении, сливаются, образуя новое супплетивное местоимение, именительный падеж всех родов и чисел местоимения ***и** полностью перестаёт употребляться и заменяется именительным падежом местоимения **онъ** (ед. ч.: м. р. **онъ**, ср. р. **оно**, ж. р. **она**, мн. ч. м. р. **они**), остальные же падежи это новое местоимение сохраняет от ***и** (**ѥго**, **ѥму**, и т. д.).

Именительный падеж от ***и** (***ѥ** [*je], ***ꙗ** [*ja]) исчез так давно, что ни в каких письменных источниках он не зарегистрирован, его можно увидеть лишь в сочетании с частицей -же: иже (ѥже, ꙗже) – «который (которое, которая)». С другой стороны, **онъ** (**оно**, **она**) в значении личного местоимения стал отличаться ударением от того же местоимения в значении указательного, личное: онó, онá; указательное: óно, óна.

В старославянском личное местоимение ж. р. в им. п. было ***ꙗ** [*ja], вин. п. - ѭ [jǫ], что должно было бы дать совр. *ю (что в точности соответствовало бы совр. окончаниям прилагательных: *велику-**ю***), но оно не сохранилось, вместо него с развитием категории одушевленность-неодушевленность стал использовался род. п. этого же местоимения, ѥѩ [jeję], который и дал **ея**. Именно эту форму и использовал русский литературный письменный язык, ориентировавшийся на старославянскую/церковнославянскую орфографию.

В устной речи, однако, издревле, примерно с XII-XIII в. использовалась форма **её**. Дело в том, что в общевосточнославянском языке род. п. от ***ꙗ** [*ja] был не ѥѩ [jeję], а **ѥѣ** [jejě]. Очень рано [ě] перешло в [e], которое в свою очередь было заменено на [о] по аналогии с твёрдыми вариантами склонения существительных и местоимений, так под влиянием *то*, *оно*, *само* возникают формы [mo'jo], [tvo'jo], [vsʲo], ср. украинские *моє*, *твоє*, *все*.

Реформа правописания 1918 года всё поставила на свои места, мёртвое церковнославянское **ея** было отменено, а живое русское **её** стало орфографической нормой.

Сходство падежных окончаний прилагательных с формами косвенных падежей местоимений 3-го лица объясняется тем, что к прилагательным в краткой форме добавлялись личные местоимения 3-го лица, образовывая определённую форму прилагательных, как бы с определённым артиклем, это называется [местоименные прилагательные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8C#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BB.D0.B0.D0.B3.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5), другое название – членные прилагательные, от них и происходят современные русские полные прилагательные.

——————————————————————————

О происхождении формы **её** [можно почитать](http://mling.ru/iazik/russe/gramm_hist.pdf) в книге: Иванов В. В., «Историческая грамматика русского языка», 3-е изд., М., 1990

– возникновение формы **её**: §199, стр. 283-284

– замена [e] на [о]: §125, стр. 184

– краткие и полные прилагательные, их окончания: §§205-213, стр. 291-300